# Remove background from ImageCardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv, leanback

I started using new `android.support.v17.leanback` library and have some trouble in styling `ImageCardView`.

I am changing the image on `ImageCardView` to have a different shape so I would like to remove background and shadow which are automatically generated when using the card in `ListRow` for example. If I leave the shadow, my card looks weird because shadow and background are showing like the card is square.

I've tried to set the different background to all the elements but it doesn't work. If I set the normal background color (green, blue, etc), the background of the image or info area would change but if I set the transparent background, another background which wraps the whole card would be visible.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Post your relevant code here.

Comment: @Astagron Did you manage it to use a transparent background?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is not about the `CardView` itself, it's about your presenter. Put this line your `RowPresenter`/`ListRowPresenter`:

```
listRowPresenter.setShadowEnabled(false);
```

Furthermore, in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/google-developers/customizing-leanback-for-android-tv-3f8d4a0b2839?linkId=55514485) you can see how to make you `CardView` circular. And where it shows how to remove the shadow when the row is not focused, overriding the `isUsingDefaultListSelectEffect()` method to be always `false`.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924560/setting-the-background-image-of-a-cardview-inside-recyclerview-causes-the-progra), you cannot change the background drawable, only the color.

You can try

```
public void setBackground (Drawable background)
-Set the background to a given Drawable, or remove the background
```