# Android TV: unfocused image contains black transparent background?

Tags: java, android, android-tv

My Android TV app fetches images from a server and displays it on the home screen. The problem is, all the images that are not focused, i.e. not selected contains a black transparent background.

The only image that does not contain a transparent background is the currently selected image. I ensured that the images were pngs. As soon as the image is focused, the background is removed.

I'm not using a `LinearLayout` or anything in the .xml, just a `GridItemPresenter` class.

What is causing this and how can I fix this?

I tried to add the following `view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)` but that has no effect.

Here's my code:

```
private class GridItemPresenter extends Presenter
{
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent)
    {       
        ImageView view = new ImageView(parent.getContext());

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int)x, (int)y));
        view.setFocusable(true);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item)
    {
        ImageView imageView = ( (ImageView) viewHolder.view);

    }

    public void onUnbindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder)
    {
        ImageView imageView = ( (ImageView) viewHolder.view);
    }
}
```

The face contains a black background when un-selected, but since it is selected, the background is not there:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can attach a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Did you make sure to check the image to see that the background is there?

Comment: Without digging deeper I can't think of anything else that Android is resizing unselected image and just loosing alpha channel :/

Comment: @Pangu Do you want all the images background as transparent either it's selected or not selected ?

Comment: I want all background images to be transparent regardless if selected or unselected

Comment: What mechanism are you using to load the images? From the network? Using Picasso or Fresco or ...?

Comment: are you fix this?face the same problem, i use TextView

Comment: Similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624317/remove-background-from-imagecardview/42490914#42490914

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to fix this. `VertiGridPresenter`'s  dimmer  default is `true` , set it to `false` like:

```
VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_NONE, false);
```

or change the theme item `<item name="overlayDimDimmedLevel">10%</item>`
in `@style/Theme.Leanback`, the percent value set the transparent value when set 100% the  background will black.